# Why assign a method to a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, methods

I see code written like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = GetInfo(); //this variable contains the method below
    Console.Writeline(name)
}

static string GetInfo()
{
    string name = "MyName";
    return (name);
}
```

Let's use the typical box example. What's a good example for method inside it?

In other words, what does it mean 'a value' = 'a method that does something'

Comment: That's not a method, it's a _value-tuple_.

Comment: Edited. Is it now?

Comment: No, it's still a tuple. If you give the return value a name it's a tuple.

Comment: Hope it is now. Guide me, new software engineering student here.

Comment: The variable does not contain the method, it contains the value returned from the method. But it's hard to understand what your problem is, here. Are you asking why you should separate code into multiple methods?

Comment: I understand now that it contains whatever value returned from the method. No, no any major problem. I'm attending coding bootcamps and doing Udemy courses, some things seems bizarre in the beginning I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not assigning a method, it is just getting the result of that executed method. In this way you can reuse **GetInfo();** in other places where ever you need this name.